# Error 0x800401F3 One process works one doesn't same website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, ssis

I'm stuck on this one. I hope someone here has some experience with this. Here is the situation. I have set up a web page that allows users to upload flat files to be loaded into SQL Server 2005 using SSIS. There are two difference SSIS processes depending on the file type. The decision of which SSIS process to use is made by the user on the website.

Once the file is uploaded by the user the process is started by a .NET Process object. The command line is the normal command line you'd expect to see to start dtexec with a specific SSIS file and that sets a couple variables. For example:

dtexec /f  /De  /set  value

The ASP.NET Anonymous User is running as a domain user account. All SSIS package files for both SSIS processes are in the same directory. The domain user account has full privileges on that directory. The same method in ASP.NET starts either of the processes. The only difference is the WebMethod called by the website. One WebMethod for each type. It is in these WebMethods where the unique arguments are assigned to the command line text for SSIS.

Here is where I have run into the problem. When running the website process "1", it runs fine, but process "2" fails with the error mentioned above. When I capture the Standard Output I receive this:

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute
>   Package Utility Version 9.00.4035.00
>   for 32-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.
>
> Started: 10:34:14 AM Could not create
>   DTS.Application because of error
>   0x800401F3 Started: 10:34:14 AM
>   Finished: 10:34:14 AM Elapsed: 0.016
>   seconds

I don't understand how everything can be nearly identical yet only one will run. One final thing, both methods work fine when I am testing directly from Visual Studio. I figure it must be something with the Anonymous User account used, but I can't figure out why one process would work and the other not work when they are so similar.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. The error code was a phantom.  What happened was a Connection Component was being fed by a variable that was holding a path to a folder the new account could not go to. Even though in process it would be replaced with a good target it was failing in validation. This is why there was no logs. I didn't have the logging level high enough to see it and it acted like a security issue. Which is was in a way of looking at it.